# Laravel: No puedo levantar proyecto en versión 5.2.45

Tags: laravel

Tengo que trabajar en un proyecto en Laravel 5.2.45 y me pidieron no actualizarlo a una nueva versión.

Pero al intentar levantarlo con:

```
php artisan serve
```

Y esto me generá los errores típicos sobre conexión al servidor:

> No se puede conectar
> Firefox no puede establecer una conexión con el servidor en 127.0.0.1:8000.
> El sitio podría estar no disponible temporalmente o demasiado ocupado. Vuelva a intentarlo en unos momentos.
> Si no puede cargar ninguna página, compruebe la conexión de red de su equipo.
> Si su equipo o red están protegidos por un cortafuegos o proxy, asegúrese de que Firefox Developer Edition tiene permiso para acceder a la web.

Intente desde la carpeta del proyecto:

```
composer install
```

Pero sólo me envió un mensaje diciendo que no eran necesarias actualizaciones.

Cambie el .env por otro de proyectos que si me levantan y tampoco.

Para el servidor local uso Xampp y les comento que ya tengo otros proyectos en marcha en versiones 5.8, 6.0, 7+, etc. que si me levantan, pero sólo este es el del problema y me urge solucionarlo.

Gracias...

Comment: El puerto de conexión es el 8000?

Comment: Listo, me orientaste con esa pregunta... Estaba colocando en el navegador http://127.0.0.1:8000 y tenía que colocar: http://localhost:8000

Comment: Entonces ya lo resolviste?

Comment: Si estas trabajando con artisan no necesitas servidor web. El mismo artisan levanta uno.